# Convert and stream videos

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-streaming, jwplayer

I am going to develop a php script on linux based server which will be used to upload videos on server and stream to users. I have seen many open source free/paid libraries available with flash,html5 etc players. After research I have decided to go with ffmpeg to convert videos and use jwPlayer with RTMP protocol to stream videos.

I am not much familiar with streaming concept but I have researched a lot on this subject since few days, so last I thought to ask here if I am going the correct way to achieve my goals, which are listed below:

1. My main concern is to start streaming videos as soon page is loaded.
2. Convert videos after upload ( Found ffmpeg for this purpose is well suited )
3. Seeking video should be faster (which after searching I found is good with RTMP protocol)

Please can someone guide me if I am going in the right direction by choosing ffmpeg, jwplayer with RTMP protocol. Thanks a lot for any guidance.

Comment: I would think you are going in the right direction here.

Comment: Thank you :), if I may...are you representative of LongTail videos or is that your name ? Sorry to ask you but as jwplayer is from that company so I could not stop :)

Comment: yeah thought so :) nice to meet you and thanks again.

Comment: Np :) Yes, I work at LongTail. Nice to meet you too.